# Where is system/library/extensions in OSX 10.10?

Tags: macos, vmware

so I am now using vmware player to mount the osx now, and since I accidentally installed the svga display driver with the vmware tool one from darwin now I cant change the resolution of it so I need to uninstall the svga. I try to find system/library/extensions so that I can uninstall the svga driver but I cant find it in the library. Where can I find it or it is just hidden in the library folder?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

⌘-Shift-G is the hotkey for the "Go to Folder" dropdown menu. Just type in /System/Library/Extensions and click Go to open that folder.

P.S. I think your screenshot may be in your User folder, not the System folder. The System folder lives in Macintosh HD, not within a specific user's files.

Comment: thanks and it works! So one more question about how it works on mac, so basically if I delete the file in extension the extension will disappear and that is equal to uninstall in mac right?

Comment: yes I think you are right, I type ~/Library to take that screenshot and I thought that is the same as system library.

Comment: If the extension came from VMWare, you may want to search around for a VMWare-approved uninstall method first. If a display driver suddenly disappears, I wouldn't trust the VM to not freeze up on the spot. If you really can't find an alternative method, then take a backup of your VM first (just in case) and then see what deleting the extension does.